# How to import demo content of wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a wordpress web site,  so I downloaded a wordpress theme, then I activate it, but it doesn't look like the theme demo. After searching on web, I notice that I have to import demo content by importing xml file of the theme, but I can't find this file. Is it true that the demo content is only included in premium theme?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , actually it is originally included inside premium purchased theme , once you find the file you can import it using wp-cli tool via command line.

```
wp import filename.xml --authors=create
```

This is the best technique to import the demo content/any content without breaking from timeout.

Source : [WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/import/)

Comment: So I can't import demo content because I'm using a free wordpress theme :(. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: All wordpress themes that I download don't like the demo, slider, widget ... disappear !!

Comment: yeah which theme you are trying actually.?

Comment: Honestly, I tried many themes, for example allegiant, corporate key, business eye. Do you know any nice theme ?

Comment: Try x theme , you can find it easily with demo content : https://dlwordpress.com/x-the-theme-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Do you have another choice?

Comment: I found this site that sugget a list of themes with demo content, but the problem that I found I can't change site logo. Here is the link, hope you have idea how to solve that: http://templatetoaster.com/showcase/page/3?utm_source=q1&utm_medium=m1&utm_campaign=n1#038;utm_medium=m1&utm_campaign=n1

Comment: There are so many templates : for which template you want to change the logo?

Comment: Re estate theme. Anyway thank you, I changed the theme.